# Converting phpmyadmin Country ISO Code to Veriable Define Value PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use a drop down list which values are ISO 3 digit country code when user selected the value goes to DB(phpmyadmin). Now for America, db has USA and different for different countries.

in my page I DEFINE the country code as country name like below

```
$nm = array(
    'GBR'    =>   "United Kingdom",
    'USA'    =>   "United States",
    'UMI'    =>   "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
    'URY'    =>   "Uruguay",
    'UZB'    =>   "Uzbekistan",
);

foreach($nm as $key => $val)
    define($key, $val);
```

As I understand from the code above, if I  `echo USA; it is printing United States`

But when I fetch the country code from DB and print the code, its printing the same code but not the defined value. I am very much confuse why its happen. Please suggest me.

I want when I print the country code from the db it should print the define value

I am fetching the query as

```
$staff_citizen = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select staff_citizen from staff_record where staff_code = '254125'"));
echo $staff_citizen[0];
```

As asked by Itsols, the field names are
staff_id (INT), staff_name(VARCHAR), staff_code(INT), staff_citizen(VARCHAR), staff_batch(INT)

Comment: What is the table structure you use to store the details? Please include it in your question

Comment: Table Type is InnoDB and Collation is UTF8_bin

Comment: I think you did not get what I meant. Please LIST your field names in the table

Comment: yah I made it, please let me you if you need anything more.

Comment: Are you storing the country code in staff_citizen?

Comment: Include the PART of your program that fetches and prints out the records with the code

Comment: yes I ma storing the country code in staff_citizen and I added the fetching query from db. The value stored for this staff is USA and I want to print United States

Comment: Since you've included code as well now, I see that you're using mysql_fetch... The **mysql_** set of functions is now considered obsolete and insecure. Use the replacement functions **mysqli_** which is quite similar for most older functions.

Comment: I am working for your below answer i will let you know.. can I just replace sql to sqli  ??

Comment: many questions are on SO and other sites that explain the differences and how to change to mysqli. Please go through them and post a fresh question if you think you need help.

Comment: Note that your database program is (likely) actually MySQL; phpMyAdmin is an  tool for administrators to maintain a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have TWO simple ways of achieving this WITHOUT using DEFINES.

**Method 1:**

When you read the field name for the staff_citizen field, simply get it off from your array without the define.
Eg: Assuming `$Fields` is what you've got, the following code should do it.

```
echo $nm[ $Fields["staff_citizen"] ];
```

**Method 2:**
Without using an array, you can have a second table with country codes and names. Then do a simple inner join query and get the names.
Eg: Assuming you have a second table `countries` with `code` and `country` as fields, you can do the query like this:

```
Select * from
countries inner join staff
on code = staff_citizen
```

Then just print the country field using php. No need for an array here.

Comment: Woww its work very easily thank y;ou very very much dear.. I thought to change all the coding... really. its help me.. Take care.. bye..